# BuildBundleMinifier Not Translating my JavaScript Correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, minify, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the latest version of [BuildBundleMinifier][1] (3.2.449) in my ASP.NET CORE project (latest version).

When it minifies my code, it drops a variable in my method signature (see code below). Also dropping some semicolons.

Here is some sample output (which I 'pretty-printed' to display here), **note that the parameter 'jqhdr' is missing** (5th line from bottom)

```js
    function SignIn() {
        var t = $("#txtPassword").val(),
            u = $("#txtUserEmail").val(),
            n = $("#txtUserName").val(),
            i = document.getElementById("hdnRC").value,
            r = getTheBaseURL(theControllerName) + "LogIn";
        $.ajax({
            url: r,
            type: "Post",
            data: {
                userName: n,
                password: t,
                rc: i
            },
            cache: !1,
            success: function(t) {
                var i, u, r;
                t > 0 && (i = parseInt($("#hdnVoteVal").val()), i == 1 || i == -1 ? (u = $("#hdnInterestingItemId").val(), recordVote(u, i)) : (r = $("#hdnReplyTxtId").val(), r == "txtNewComment" ? saveCommentAjax(r) : BuildCommentReplyControls(r)), $("#dlgLogIn").modal("hide"), appendLogoutToHeader(n))
            },
            //Note: the original code was "error: function(jqhdr)"
            error: function() {
                logException(jqhdr.responseText, "SignIn", "MostInterestingDetails")
            }
        })
    }


  [1]: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier

Edit: my bundleconfig.json looks like this:
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js",
      "wwwroot/js/AccountAndComments.js",
      "wwwroot/js/AmenityDetails.js",
      "wwwroot/js/CastleForRentDetails.js",
      "wwwroot/js/CastleForRentIndex.js",
      "wwwroot/js/CastleHome.js",
      "wwwroot/js/CastleType.js",
      "wwwroot/js/GeneralDiscussionIndex.js",
      "wwwroot/js/MostBeautiful.js",
      "wwwroot/js/MostInterestingDetails.js",
      "wwwroot/js/MostInterestingItemCreate.js",
      "wwwroot/js/QuestIndex.js",
      "wwwroot/js/Tourist.js",
      "wwwroot/js/Tournament.js",
      "wwwroot/js/Utilities.js",
      "wwwroot/js/VirtualTourCreate.js",
      "wwwroot/js/VirtualTourIndex.js",
      "wwwroot/js/VirtualTours.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Take a look at this article which may be of help for you: https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/a-step-by-step-guide-to-bundling-and-minification-in-asp-net-core

Comment: It is because of the code error, can this line work correctly `t > 0 && (i = parseInt($("#hdnVoteVal").val()), i == 1 || i == -1 ? (u = $("#hdnInterestingItemId").val(), recordVote(u, i)) : (r = $("#hdnReplyTxtId").val(), r == "txtNewComment" ? saveCommentAjax(r) : BuildCommentReplyControls(r)), $("#dlgLogIn").modal("hide"), appendLogoutToHeader(n))`, and variable `t` is duplicated with the second line. If not the above problem, can you share the mehtod of `logException`.

Comment: Karney - The code I posted is the minified code created by BuildBundleMinifier. The original code, which was translated into this, did not have any issues. The problem is that BuildBundleMinifier is not Translating my javascript correctly.

Comment: @ActualRandy, can you share the `bundleconfig.json`? Because I can generate the file through BuildBundleMinifier.

Comment: I revised my original post to include the bundleconfig.json. However, I am pretty sure the issue is a bug in BuildBundleMinfier. [This post illustrates another programmer struggling with the identical issue](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5293666/The-cause-of-buildbundleminifier-missing-the-param)